# Web Scraping interactive Chart

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the information contained in the chart about the market values of the player (https://www.transfermarkt.de/joshua-kimmich/marktwertverlauf/spieler/161056). Unfortunately, my approach so far (using SelectorGadget) does not work with charts of this type.
I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint how to scrape the data using R or Python.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as the graph is being injected dynamically into the website via JavaScript, you have two ways of going about this task:

1. Emulate the script (unnecessary hard but fast)
2. WebScrape using a browser client (slower, but much easier)
   You can use Python libraries such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) (the second option being more modern) to handle this task. The documentation for playwright is pretty intuitive, and you can use css selectors in order to traverse the dom, which, I suppose, you already have knowledge of.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: thanks! I will try out the second option and let you know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to obtain the values with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)

url <- 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/joshua-kimmich/marktwertverlauf/spieler/161056'
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

################
#### Values ####
################
html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
text <- str_extract_all(html_Content, pattern = '<path fill="none"[^>]*></path>')[[1]]
text <- text[nchar(text) > 200]
text <- text[1]
text <- stringr::str_split(text, pattern = " L ")[[1]]
text <- stringr::str_remove_all(text, pattern = "<path fill=\"none\" d=\"M|\" stroke=\"#314f77\" stroke-width=\"2\" zIndex=\"1\" stroke-linejoin=\"round\" stroke-linecap=\"round\"></path>")
text <- stringr::str_remove_all(text, pattern = "^ ")
text <- stringr::str_split(text, pattern = "[:space:]")
values_Y <- lapply(X = text, FUN = function(x) x[2])
values_X <- unlist(lapply(X = text, FUN = function(x) x[1]))
values_X <- as.numeric(values_X)
values_Y <- unlist(values_Y)
values_Y  <- as.numeric(values_Y)
values_Y  <- (306 - values_Y) / 306
values_Y

##############
#### Time ####
##############
html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
time <- str_extract_all(html_Content, pattern = '<tspan[^>]*>\\d{4}</tspan>')[[1]]
years_X <- str_extract_all(time, pattern = ">\\d{4}<")
years_X  <- str_remove_all(years_X, pattern = ">|<")
years_X <- as.numeric(years_X)
coord_X <- unlist(str_extract_all(time, "\\d{2,3}\\.\\d{1,20}"))
coord_X <- as.numeric(coord_X)

data <- data.frame(years_X, coord_X)
obj_Mod <- lm(years_X ~ coord_X, data = data)
inter_Fun <- function(x) obj_Mod$coefficients[1] + obj_Mod$coefficients[2] * (x + 33)

Y <- values_Y
X <- inter_Fun(values_X)
df <- data.frame(Y, X)
colnames(df) <- c("Value", "Year")
df
         Value     Year
1  0.006258170 2013.603
2  0.008251634 2014.063
3  0.010245098 2014.493
4  0.018218954 2014.748
5  0.053104575 2015.033
6  0.053104575 2015.495
7  0.083006536 2016.122
8  0.102941176 2016.281
9  0.132843137 2016.415
10 0.202614379 2016.555
11 0.252450980 2017.102
12 0.252450980 2017.464
13 0.401960784 2017.989
14 0.551470588 2018.255
15 0.551470588 2018.425
16 0.601307190 2018.961
17 0.700980392 2019.424
18 0.800653595 2019.958
19 0.641176471 2020.267
20 0.750816993 2020.516
21 0.850490196 2020.708
22 0.900326797 2021.111
23 0.900326797 2021.414
24 0.850490196 2021.973
25 0.800653595 2022.436
26 0.800653595 2022.855
```